# Attempting to show multiple checkboxes using more than one column HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have successfully managed to return all the 'tags' from my MySQL database table into checkboxes so the user can select a few.

Currently it is displaying as one long column which isn't very efficient as the modal screen size is quite small. I was wondering if there was a way to break it up and display it into 3 columns instead of just the one.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: Tag modal]

any ideas on how i can achieve my end goal to look similar to this:

[image: End Goal]

This is the entire code i have at the moment:

```
    <?php

      include "db_conx.php";

      try
        {

      $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

        $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT * FROM tag_details ORDER BY tag_title ASC');
        $stmt->execute();
        //$count = $stmt>rowCount();
        $tags = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
        $e->getMessage();
        }


    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles2.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src='js/index.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#addPModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

        });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    var limit = 3;
    $('input.checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
        if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
  });
  </script>
  <style>

.checkbox-inline{
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}

  </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-lg pull-right" role="group">

    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPModal" data-id="#">Add New Proposal</button>
    </div><p/>
  </div>

  <div id="addPModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addPModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Showing All Tags </h4>
                <p class="text-danger"><small>(Select up to 3)</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="viewForm">

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="course_details">Select Tags:</label><p></p>
                        <div class="checkbox-inline">
                            <?php foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
                            <div>
                                <input name='tag[]' class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $tag['tag_code'] ?>"><?php echo $tag['tag_title'] ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

new screenshot with css changes as advised:
[image: Updated]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set a max-height to parent container and then put a float left to each checkbox

Comment: I've done this in the past by dividing the number of items by the number of columns you want and then looping through them accordingly (i.e. pull down 12 items, initialize a counter and create a new div/td when you start, end, and after every 4th item giving you three columns)

Comment: @Jason'Jaypoc'Bauman thanks for the reply. by any chance do you have an example i can look at? thanks

Comment: Look at columns: https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qfrqdxzy/

Comment: By the way, you have some extra </p> tags in that code.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird thanks for your help. I'll have a look at those links. I've tried the webkit code form the jsfiddle and it does't seem to work - is 'webkit' some sort of framework? I've not messed with css much yet

Comment: you can use an html table

Comment: I think I like the CSS method better, but I did this years ago with just PHP/HTML Tables as in my example.

Comment: @user90210 the -webkit and -moz prefixes are browser specific.  -webkit will be for Chrome and Safari.

Comment: thanks @BarbaraLaird i've managed to get it to work with the css kind of but I'm getting a weird look. Its separated the list into 3 columns but doesn't align the words with the checkbox. please take a look at my updated question with a new screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Here's some very basic code I just wrote up to explain my comment. I wouldn't use this verbatim, but it works:

```
<?php

$list = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G');
$ctr = 1;

print "<table><tr><td valign=top>";
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list); $i++)
{
    if ($ctr == 5)  { $ctr = 1; print "</td><td valign=top>"; }
    print $list[$i];
    print "<br/>";
    $ctr++;
}
print "</td></tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: I get it's example code, but not digging the tables and **valign** attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of ways you could tackle this. It looks like you're using Twitter Bootstrap so you can use the `.checkbox-inline` class to [inline all your checkbox inputs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline-checkboxes-and-radios).

From there you need to decide how you want to break up each set of three. You could do this by wrapping them in a DIV of their own or adding a break tag `<br>` after every third one.

I like to use the *modulus* operator for such tasks and might look something like this:

```php
<?php
     $count = 0;
     $length = count($tags);
     foreach ( $tags as $tag ) :
?>
     <input name='tag[]' type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $tag['tag_code'] ?>"> <?php echo $tag['tag_title'] ?>
<?php
     $count++; // you could pre-incremment $count in the if statement
     if ( $count % 3 === 0 && $count !== $length ) {
          echo '<br>';
     }
     endforeach;
?>
```

Also, input tags are self closing, you do not need the `</input>` or `<input/>`. You are specifying your document as HTML5 so `<input>` will do (no slash).

Comment: thanks @hungerstar ill give this a go. Seem to be having problems with adding in the count stuff to the php code because i've opened and closed the statements which require php. would i need to do the same for the count stuff?

Comment: For sure, and I totally forgot to take that into account. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You might want to include a check so that there is no output on the last iteration of the loop. For example, if you had 33 fields then you would have output as `if ( 33 % 3 === 0 )` would be true. To prevent that, count the length of the array before hand and make sure the count is not equal to that value before you output: `if ( $count % 3 === 0 && $count !== $length )`. I have added this check to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method using CSS columns and only form elements. It looks like this:

[image: Column Screenshot]

**Compatibility:** [IE 10 + and all modern browsers using `-moz` and `-webkit` prefixes.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

### The HTML

- Contain the inputs and labels in a fieldset (instead of that div) and title it with a legend:

  ```
  <fieldset class="checkbox-inline">
      <legend>Checkbox List</legend>

      <!-- inputs and labels go here -->
  </fieldset>
  ```

  **Note: The fieldset wont work with Firefox, keep using a div**. There [appears to be a long term bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727164) that prevents CSS columns from working on fieldset elements :( I will keep the fieldset for my example as an ideal element to use here, but use a div for production.
- Discard the divs around the inputs and wrap the inputs in their labels instead; this ensures that the label text is aligned with the checkbox:

  ```
  <label for="check1">
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>
  ```

### With the PHP

- With your PHP it would look something like this:

  ```
  <fieldset class="checkbox-inline">
      <legend class="control-label" for="course_details">Select Tags:</legend>
      <?php foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
      <label>
          <input class="checkbox" name='tag[]' type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $tag['tag_code'] ?>">
          <?php echo $tag['tag_title'] ?>
      </label>
      <?php endforeach ?>
  </fieldset>
  ```

### Add some simple CSS

- Use CSS columns placed on the `.checkbox-inline` fieldset class:

  ```
  .checkbox-inline {
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
  }
  ```
- The labels are given `display: block` so each will be one line and `white-space: nowrap` ensures the text will always align with the input
- Style the fieldset as desired, the example below has some padding and `display: inline-block` so no width needs to be declared

### Complete Example

```css
.checkbox-inline {
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  -moz-columns: 3;
  columns: 3;
  border: solid 5px #F00;
  padding: 40px 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.checkbox-inline label {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
legend {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px
}
```

```html
<!-- Use a div and not a fieldset here for the moment due to Firefox bug -->
<fieldset class="checkbox-inline">
  <legend>Checkbox List</legend>
  <label for="check1">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>

  <label for="check2">
    <input id="check2" type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>

  <label for="check3">
    <input id="check3" type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>

  <label for="check4">
    <input id="check4" type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>

  <label for="check5">
    <input id="check5" type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>

  <label for="check6">
    <input id="check6" type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Just a note about browser support, the **columns** property is supported in IE10+, http://caniuse.com/#search=columns. Otherwise I think you are good to go with this solution.